# Android Webview can't show jpg images with more than 3000 pixels height

Tags: android, webview

I am using a WebView in an Android Activity to show a simple html who has a single jpg inside. When the jpg height is smaller than 3000 pixels, there is no problem, it show perfectly, but when the jpg is above 3000 pixels, it does not show. Can be this a limitation? Or memory issue? I am using Android 2.3 to test.

Comment: That's an enormous image. Considering that bitmaps use 4 bytes per pixel in memory, a 3000 x 3000 image takes over 34 megabytes!

Comment: To be fair, he didn't specify the width.  Could be a 1x3000 pixel strip.  In practice I'd guess you're right, and the logcat output likely holds an appropriate complaint.

Comment: Krylez, the width is around 500. It is a jpg file color 256 with 222Kbytes total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using a huge image, so the device can't handle that much data.
In order to display it properly and nicely mi advice is to use an **html table** wich **each cell containing a slice of the image**.

The browser will just render the parts of the table being displayed, so your image will be loaded properly.

I used this approach on a project and worked perfectly.

Regards.

Comment: Zadec, thanks for the suggestion, do you know where I can get a sample on how to do this?

Comment: This is a brief example of how the table will look.

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tr><td><img src="tile_1.png" alt="" border="0"/></td><td><img src="tile_2.png" alt="" border="0" /></td></tr>
   <tr><td><img src="tile_n.png" alt="" border="0"/></td><td><img src="tile_n+1.png" alt="" border="0" /></td></tr>
</table>